# Do some Wii games require a Classic Controller?

Tags: nintendo-wii, controllers

Are there any Wii games that require me to use a Classic Controller and won't work with a Gamecube controller or Wiimote+Nunchuck? Are there any controllers that have both a Wiimote and a Gamecube plug so I don't have to buy two similar controllers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there are no games that require a classic controller but do not work with either a gamecube controller or the wiimote & nunchuck combination.

There are games however that only support two out of the three combinations, most notably, Monster Hunter Tri, which only supports the classic controller and the wiimote+nunchuck combination, but do not support the Gamecube controller

Do note however that some games are not optimized for the gamecube controller and play a lot easier on the classic controller (SNES games notably) and the gamecube controller is the only controller that allows you to play gamecube games.

Comment: Thanks. So in general, one would need both a GC and a Classic Controller (unless the Wiimote+Nunchuck combo is ok). Which led me to this question: [Are there adapters to use one controller (possibly Xbox) as both Wii classic controller and as Gamecube controller?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8194/88)

Answer (score 4):

No. To the best of my knowledge, a Gamecube controller will work for all of the games that state that they require the classic controller; if you already own a Wavebird or Wired gamecube controller, you do not need to purchase the classic controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so either. But I'm pissy about MegaMan 9 and Samurai Shodown - they support classic but not GC controller. It was exactly these types of games I bought the GC controller for. On the other hand, Mario Kart and Smash Brothers and virtual console games all support GC controller, which I like.

Comment: Maybe there is an adapter to use a GC controller as CC. In case you find one, please post it as answer on [Are there adapters to use one controller (possibly Xbox) as both Wii classic controller and as Gamecube controller?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8194/88)