# Are there adapters to use one controller (possibly Xbox) as both Wii classic controller and as Gamecube controller?

Tags: nintendo-wii, controllers

Basically I want to have one single gamepad (and I like the Xbox layout best, but it's not imperative), so I am searching for one of the following solutions:

- One or two adapters USB (at least Xbox compatible) -> GC & Wii Classic Controller
- One adapter GC -> Wii CC or vice versa

Comment: slightly related: [Are there Wii-games which require a classic controller but won't work with a gamecube controller or wiimote+nunchuck?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7261/88)

Comment: +1, & favourited:  Excellent Question!  I've wondered this myself!

Comment: @TomWij: it wouldn't necessarily have to be a wireless xbox controller, wired is ok as well. Although the idea of directly using its bluetooth (didn't know it uses that, why does one have to buy an extra xbox dongle for pc then?) as a fake wiimote is intriguing

Comment: Oh, if there exist a wired controller for the Xbox then it is possible. And I was assuming the wrong Wii controller too! Nevermind... But still, it's like looking for a needle in a haystack. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES, there is an adapter, the [Classic Linker from EMS](http://www.hkems.com/product/nintendo/0803.htm) (also in the [Plus](http://www.hkems.com/product/nintendo/0902.htm) and [N64](http://www.hkems.com/product/nintendo/0908.htm) variants) that allows you to connect the Wii Classic Controller as a Gamecube controller, allowing you to play gamecube games with a Classic Controller. (You might want to get the N64 variant, as according to the documentation, the other two have weird button layouts.)

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot, that's quite what I wanted (now I could even use my old N64 controller!), but you're right about the mapping.

Comment: also thanks for the direct link saving me from the eye hurting of their main page... But I had to look at it to see the price :-7 25 USD = approx 17 EUR. Hm, I can buy a new GC controller for 10 EUR... But you deserve the bounty for your research in any case

Comment: @tobias, you might also want to accept this answer, indicating the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

A GameCube controller already does this.  It, along with third party GameCube controllers are probably the only ones that will work with both the GameCube and Wii.  However, you don't plug the GameCube controller into the Wiimote, but instead directly into the Wii.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to use a GameCube controller for GC mode or virtual console games which explicitly support that, but I mean really using one controller as both GC *and* Classic Controller, since there are games which don't support GC controllers, e.g. Monster Hunter Tri (see alexandrepas' answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/are-there-wii-games-which-require-a-classic-controller-but-wont-work-with-a-game/7264#7264)). OTOH I obviously want to be able to use GC mode which can't access a Classic Controller. But I don't want to have to buy two controllers.

Comment: Then my guess is you're hooped.  Admittedly, I'm only going on what I've learned from using friend's Wiis since I don't own one myself.  There may be a third party Classic Controller that also has a GameCube connector (or vice versa), but I haven't seen it.